# Is it possible to return partials without rendering them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, templates, collections, rendering

I have one partial that I would liked returned from two different sets of data.

```
@data_a = @replies
@data_b = @users
```

They both can be fed through this partial :

```
render partial: 'vis_item', collection: @replies
```

The problem is that I want to return in my controller both collections separately,

```
# not working code, just a guess
render { replies: 'vis_item', collection: @replies, users: 'vis_item', collection: @users }
```

If the code is returned in a hash like this, I could disseminate it with my jQuery success callback :

```
success: (data) ->
  $(".user-block").html data.users
  $(".replies-block").html data.replies
```

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `render_to_string`.  Works exactly the same, except returns a string.

http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Rendering/render_to_string

Comment: That's it! Thanks Philip! I just have to wait the 8 more minutes out. Thanks again!